# ActionLink pass parameter to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Started from the beginning, I have a list view in my MVC5 App. I have links to action like Edit and Delete. If I click on Delete I want to show Bootstrap Modal Popup, which I already have. But the problem is I have Html.ActionLink which promperly redirects my Modal Popup to the method that I specified in ActionLink. I want to just show popup and then click submit or something else and then do the action. But there was another problem - in what way I can pass parameter from my list view to modal popup ?

Some code below:

```
@model IEnumerable<SupportStudentSystem.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List of Categories";
}

<h1 class="text-center">Categories</h1>

<div style="margin-top:1%">
    <a href="AddCategory" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Category</a>
</div>
<table class="table" style="margin-top:2%">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequiredAge)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequiredAge)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditCategory", "Admin", new { item.CategoryID }, null) |
                 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCategory", "Admin", new { item.CategoryID }, new {data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#Delete" })                </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

And here is my modal:

```
<div class="modal active" id="Delete" role="dialog" style="overflow-y:auto">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Delete Category</h3>
    </div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p style="text-align:center"><strong> Do you want to delete this category ? </strong> </p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DeleteCategory", "Admin")'" class="btn btn-default">Delete category</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
```

In DeleteCategory method I delete category which has a specified CategoryID passed like a parameter, and then delete it also from database.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using jQuery, you can define a handler for onclick event to catch click on your delete ActionLink. So, at first give an id to your ActionLink and store a parameter in data attribute:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCategory", "Admin", new { item.CategoryID }, new {data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#Delete", id="deleteActionLink", data_parameter="<here goes your parameter>" })
```

Then in jQuery code add a variable for your parameter and event handler:

```
var parameter;
$("#deleteActionLink").on("click", function(){
    //save your parameter in variable
    parameter = $("#deleteActionLink").data("parameter"); 
});
```

Then add one more handler, only for submit button on your modal, and send a post request from here (using ajax)

Comment: I tried with Html.ActionLink and <a href> also, but neither seems to be working and I don't know why. I have this ActionLink: `@Html.ActionLink("Usuń", "DeleteCategory", "Admin", new { item.CategoryID }, new {data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#Delete", id = "deleteActionLink", data_parameter = @item.CategoryID })`

and that jQuery function:
 `var parameter;
    $("#deleteActionLink").on("click", function (e) {
        //save your parameter in variable
        parameter = $("#deleteActionLink").data('id');
        $(".modal-footer #categoryID").val(parameter);
    });`

Comment: I am not quite sure, but try to add this line to click handler:

Comment: Try to pass a parameter to your handler `$("#deleteActionLink").on("click", function(event){
    //save your parameter in variable
    event.preventDefault();
    parameter = $("#deleteActionLink").data("parameter"); 
});`
Maybe the standart ActionLink functionality is interferring

Comment: I am not sure why you used `$(".modal-footer #categoryID").val(parameter);`. I prepared a little example. Hope it helps. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ab8oLkqv/1/)